# MS Outlook 2010 - DASL Filter For Birthdate

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-filter

I am trying to filter Outlook contact view to only return contacts birthdays for today's MMDD using:"urn:schemas:contacts:bday"

Thank you!

Comment: There is no way to do that

Comment: Thank you Dmitry. Any other options to give the desired results within Outlook?

Comment: You can programmatically (once a year) set a user property that will contain the birthday for this year, then apply the view on that custom property to be in the given range.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the following one in Outlook or VBA code:

```
%today("urn:schemas:contacts:bday")%
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Eugene That options gives birthdays on today and not historic (MMDD). Any other options within Outlook?

Comment: You can set up a view in Outlook (see the Advanced tab) and then get the required filters criteria on the SQL tab to apply programmatically if needed.

Comment: Thanks. However, the filter uses today's date and not MMDD.